# How to create a monthly summary table in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

In PowerBI, I have a table with data in days

Table 1

| Day | Order |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | 3 |
| 1/31/2022 | 5 |
| 2/2/2022 | 7 |
| 2/11/2022 | 12 |
| 3/1/2022 | 31 |
| 4/31/2022 | 5 |
| 4/2/2022 | 7 |
| 6/11/2022 | 21 |

And I want to have a summary table for months like
Table 1

| Month | Order |
| --- | --- |
| 1 2022 | 8 |
| 2 2022 | 19 |
| 3 2022 | 31 |
| 4 2022 | 12 |
| 6/11/2022 | 21 |

How can I do that using DAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  Create a [Calculated Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-calculated-tables) using the [SUMMARIZECOLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/summarizecolumns-function-dax) function.

Something like:

```
OrdersByMonth = summarizecolumns(MyTable[Month], "Orders", sum(MyTable[Orders]))
```